# Dynamic grid view column from a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Would it be possible that my ASP.NET gridview columns will dynamically follow the columns returned from a SQL Server stored procedure? Can you please share some of the techniques?

Comment: Have you tried some? Anyway, use AutoGenerateGolumns=true to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Dapper Micro ORM](http://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper) to map columns generated in SQL Server Stored Procedure (or any other SQL Query ).

First you need to create a **List** of (I'm taking here Student class as example) Student Class and then simply pass to GridView datasource to it.

```
List<Student> students = getStudents(); 
gridview1.DataSource = students;
```

To Get students list

For example you can create a C# Class

```
public class Student
    {
        public int ID {get;set}
        public string Name {get;set}        
    }
```

and you have a stored procedure (or SQL Query) like 
Select ID, Name from Student

Then you can use Dapper Framework to get something like this

```
//If you using Query
List<Student> students = conn.Query<Student>("select ID,Name from Student", null, null, true, null, CommandType.Text).ToList(); 
//OR if you using stored procedure then
List<Student> students = conn.Query<Student>("StoredProcedureName", null, null, true, null, CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
```